# How can I implement my PHP curl request to Python

Tags: php, python, curl, urllib2, pycurl

This PHP code below fetches html from server A to server B. I did this to circumvent the same-domain policy of browsers. (jQuery's JSONP can also be used to achieve this but I prefer this method)

```
<?php
 /* 
   This code goes inside the body tag of server-B.com.
   Server-A.com then returns a set of form tags to be echoed in the body tag of Server-B 
 */
 $ch = curl_init();
 $url = "http://server-A.com/form.php";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,FALSE);
 curl_exec($ch);     //   grab URL and pass it to the browser
 curl_close($ch);    //   close cURL resource, and free up system resources
?>
```

How can I achieve this in Python? Im sure there is Curl implementation in Python too but I dont quite know how to do it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cURL wrappers for Python, but the preferred way of doing this is using [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)

Note that your code in PHP retrieves the *whole* page and prints it. The equivalent Python code is:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://server-A.com/form.php'
res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print res.read()
```

Comment: Yes, but I made the form.php to just output the form tags without the rest of usual content like header, foote... just the form.

Comment: If you control both servers, why do you even need to use cURL?

Comment: I only have control on Server-A.com. Server-B.com is hosted somewhere else and built on Django. I can only request (and suggest) to the guy at the other end how he can fetch data from Server-A.com in proxy kind of way .

Comment: @r2b2 You should ask him for an API. It'll be easier on you both. But if he won't cooperate, `urllib` will work just as well as cURL

Comment: I tried running your code on linux command line and it gives me this : 

NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined

Comment: @r2b2 You need to import the `urllib2` module (see my updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for: http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Sample Get Call

```
import requests

def consumeGETRequestSync():
 params = {'test1':'param1','test2':'param2'}
 url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
 headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
 # call get service with headers and params
 response = requests.get(url, headers = headers,data = params)
 print "code:"+ str(response.status_code)
 print "******************"
 print "headers:"+ str(response.headers)
 print "******************"
 print "content:"+ str(response.text)

consumeGETRequestSync()
```

You can check this blog post http://stackandqueue.com/?p=75